# Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name

Tags: apache-http-server

After restarting apache2:

```
$ apache2ctl restart

apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using 20xx:48xx:78xx:xx0:ff7:xx43:xxxx:6451 for ServerName
```

I have an entry in my /etc/hosts file for 20xx:48xx:78xx:xx0:ff7:xx43:xxxx:6451

but I am not sure this is? Is this an hexa version of my IP address? (replaced some of the digits by 'x')

What is it complaining for? and does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My computer did this every time it started up and shut down when I was running Apache httpd, but I was still able to access the local site it hosted. My guess is that it tries to detect the global IP address of the machine so it can send looped requests or something similar. If it isn't conected to the Internet, it uses a local address and reports it. I wouldn't call it a complaint.

That number is an IPv6 address. If you check with an IPv6-aware tool, you should find that that address is assigned to your server.